# Generating a simple static plot with Chart.js

Tags: flask, plot, charts, static, chart.js

I'm trying to make a static plot with Chart.js (a JavaScript library to which I am a novice still).

This I my code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('StaticPlot');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function createStaticChart() {
    const labels = ['Data Point 1', 'Data Point 2', 'Data Point 3', 'Data Point 4', 'Data Point 5'];
    const dataPoints = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1];

    const staticChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Data',
                data: dataPoints,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                tension: 0.1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
    });
}

createStaticChart();
```

Here's what has been corrected:

```
// Removed the unnecessary const config block.
// Defined the options object correctly inside the staticChart configuration.
// Removed the data argument from the createStaticChart function as the data and labels are defined within the function itself.
// Defined the labels and dataPoints arrays for the chart data.
```

// This corrected code should create a static line chart on the specified canvas element with the provided data."

I have already read the Chart.js documentation and made some corrections as suggested by ChatGPT (cf. comment section in my code) and the code looks fine to me. However, when I run my web application (realized with Python Flask), there is no chart that appears on my website. What's wrong with my code or does anyone have suggestions on how I can solve this problem? I want to understand how can realize this simple chart in order to tackle more advanced projects with Chart.js. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While trying to reproduce the issue using jsfiddle, I created this:
https://jsfiddle.net/6do1y9m8/

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="StaticPlot"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript part has not been modified.

In order to work properly, in your html code, you need to make sure that there is a `canvas` node, where the id is `StaticPlot`.

Note: If you are using a div instead of a canvas, the `getContext()` will fail.